# Запуск определенных категорий автотестов Azure DevOps

Tags: .net, azure, xunit

Есть определенные категории автотестов в проекте. Как правильно сделать их запуск в Azure когда нужно.
Правильно ли я решил, что вот сюда можно просто прописать категории тестов которые нужно запустить, и это будет работать ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Синтаксис для записи верный ?
/TestFilter "Category=About & Category=Slider"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почти, Описание деталиции задачи можно посмотреть здесь: [Visual Studio Test task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops)

Тут можно посмотреть детализацию параметра: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019

> /TestCaseFilter:[expression]

Пример:

```
/TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=Nightly|FullyQualifiedName=Namespace.ClassName.MethodName"
```

Похожий вопрос здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139803/using-vstest-console-exe-testcategory-with-equals-and-not-equals

Да и в самом шаге есть подсказака:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. Ваш пример будет выглядеть в задаче так:

```
TestCategory=About&TestCategory=Slider
```